# Certain Function On CakePHP Redirect Me To Either Blank Or HTTP 500 Page - How Can I Debug This?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I needed to upgrade my PHP version from 5.5 to 5.6 and after I noticed on my CakePHP 1.2 website that some functions take me to a blank or HTTP 500 page.

The strange part is I have a "test site" copy of my website that's also now on PHP 5.6 but I don't get this issue on my "test site".  I'm not sure if it's because my "test site" doesn't use SSL while my "live site" is all in HTTPS.

I think this might be a .htaccess issue but I'm not sure, so I would to try to debug this to see if I can see what the actual error is.

My lead developer is on vacation and I remember him fixing issue like this quickly when we first upgraded to PHP 5.5; so I think this should be something that's an easy fix.

Comment: unable to understand clearly, please share some code or at least .htaccess code

Comment: CakePHP 1.2 doesn't really work on anything newer than PHP 5.5. What errors are in your logs?